# Is there a way to move everything inside a rectangle along with the rectangle?

Tags: reporting-services

I have a rectangle that contains many elements such as textboxes, tablixes and lines. If I select the rectangle and move it, none of the contained elements move with it. The only way I've found to move all the elements inside the rectangle along with the rectangle is manually selecting each element with shift. The problem is a lot of the elements have overlapping borders making selection difficult. Is there some way to select a rectangle and move it with everything inside moving along with it?

Answer (score 1):

I suspect the rectangle is not actually the container of the elements but it is simply in the same position. It's been a while since I did anything like this so make a copy of your report before you start..

Try dragging the rectangle somewhere so it clears he elements it needs to contain. It doesn't matter where you drag it as we will move it back shortly.

Next select all the elements you want in the rectangle can hit Ctrl-X to cut them.

Next click inside your rectangle and then hit Ctrl-V to paste them. They should now be contained in the rectangle.

Finally, drag the rectangle back to it's original position.

Comment: The only thing I would suggest differently is move the rectangle to the desired position before pasting the content back in.

Comment: I understand why you say that but the action of dragging the rectangle back into position would show the OP that everything moves